# I need to use jquery validation with update panel

Tags: jquery, updatepanel

I need to use jquery validation with update panel  but update pannel refresh the validations 
how this problem can be solved

Comment: can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 3):

hai sanjay,

jQuery and MS AJAX do not play well together.  Once an asp.net 'AJAX' call is made, any jQuery assignments are lost.  YOu will have to take some extra precuations or use a little different approach to make them work.  Check out this article:

http://encosia.com/2009/03/25/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/

and this jQuery event:

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

jQuery library can be easily integrated with ASP.Net Ajax applications. Remember the ready event will not fire for an asynchronous postback caused from UpdatePanel control. The ASP.Net AJAX equivalent of ready() function is endRequest event.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
    function pageLoad()
    {      
       var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
       manager.add_endRequest(endRequest);
    }
    function endRequest(sender, args)
    {
      //Do all what you want to do in jQuery ready function
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: since these are jQuery events, do they not have to be called onClientClick? Thank you for sharing the article, it's very helpful.